# How to send a mail with a template through code in Odoo v8?

Tags: python, python-2.7, odoo-8, odoo

I'm trying to send a mail (with a template loaded) through Python.

I did this in version 7 with the function `send_mail` of the `email.template` model. Now, I want it for version 8, but I'm not able to manage this.

It's not a problem about thse SMTP server nor the template, because if I send the mail manually, it gets to its destiny rightly.

It seems that it's not going into the function `send_mail` (I've written a logger info message above the first line of the function and it never appears).

This is my code:

```
return self.env['email.template'].send_mail(
   self.env.cr, self.env.uid, template.id, self.id, force_send=True,
   context=self.env.context)
```

I've also checked that the `template.id` and the `self.id` parameters which the function needs are right. But there are no errors, no messages, it's ignoring the function. I've also tried without `cr`, `uid` and `context`, but same result.

By the way, `send_mail` function has a decorator which I had never seen before, `@api.cr_uid_id_context`, whose meaning I don't know.

Can anyone help me, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found the problem after a while. I compared my code to other modules which called the same function and I tried to emulate them.

Finally I manage it calling the `email.template` model with `pool` instead of `env`, this way:

```
return self.pool['email.template'].send_mail(
   self.env.cr, self.env.uid, template.id, self.id, force_send=True,
   context=self.env.context)
```

Now it goes into the the function and it works, mail is sent with the desired template.

Answer (score 5):

When using the new API (`self.env` instead of `self.pool`), not only do you no longer need to pass the `cr`/`uid`/`context` arguments, as you usually don't pass the `id(s)`either; instead, you `browse()` to get an object, and then call the method on it.

Try:

```py
return template.send_mail(self.id, force_send=True)
```

Comment: I found this helpful. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

once i created one template for the similar purpose ,please check it on and try to solve your problem.

```
   for rec in job_records:
         _logger.error('In project task listttttttttttttttttttttttttttttt  %s', rec.job_id.partner_id.email)
         attachment_ids = self.pool.get('ir.attachment').search(cr, uid, [('res_model','=', 'hr.applicant'),('res_id','=',rec.id),('blind_cv','=','True')])
         message = ("Hello %s \n Below Prurchase Order is  Delay Today: \n Supplier Name : %s \n Purchase Order Refereance : %s \n Order Date : %s \n Delivery Date : %s \n Product Names : %s \n\n")
        # context.update({'default_student_ids' : [(6, 0, [rec.id])]})
         vals = {'state': 'outgoing',
                         'subject': 'CVs',
                         'body_html': '<pre>%s</pre>' % message,
                         'email_to': rec.job_id.partner_id.email,
                         'email_from': 'rahuls.logicious@gmail.com',
                         'attachment_ids': [(6, 0, attachment_ids)],

                 }
         email_ids.append(self.pool.get('mail.mail').create(cr, uid, vals, context=context))
     if email_ids:
         self.pool.get('mail.mail').send(cr, uid, email_ids, context=context)
```

Comment: Thank you, I upvote you, but that code is more or less the content of the function `send_mail` and I've just found the problem. I'm going to post it.

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this :

```
def send_email(self, cr, uid, ids, vals, context=None):
    # Set Context with ids
    compose_ctx = dict(context,active_ids=ids)
    # Set your template search domain
    search_domain = [('name', '=', 'Application accepted')]
    # Get template id
    template_id = self.pool['email.template'].search(cr, uid, search_domain, context=context)[0]
    # Compose email
    compose_id = self.pool['mail.compose.message'].create(cr, uid, {
        'model': self._name,
        'composition_mode': 'mass_mail',
        'template_id': template_id,
        'post': True,
        'notify': True,
        }, context=compose_ctx)
    self.pool['mail.compose.message'].write(cr, uid, [compose_id], self.pool['mail.compose.message'].onchange_template_id(cr, uid, [compose_id], template_id, 'mass_mail', self._name, False,context=compose_ctx)['value'],context=compose_ctx)
    # Send mail with composed id
    self.pool['mail.compose.message'].send_mail(cr, uid, [compose_id], context=compose_ctx)
```